# Object is possibly 'undefined' for ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactor

Tags: angular

I want to dynamically load components which match title from the response of a web endpoint. I was following the example in the [Angular Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) tutorial.

Hi I am trying to pass a component to `resolveComponentFactory` method but I am getting a red squigly line under `most_accurate_AnswerBankItem` in the line below stating Object is possibly  'undefined'

```
 const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(most_accurate_AnswerBankItem.component)
```

The entire function below

```
  loadAnswerBankResponses(){
      this.answerserver_svc.ask_answerbank(this.question).subscribe((response:IAnswerBankResponse) => {
        let answers = response.autnresponse.responsedata.answers.answer;
        if (answers){
          let most_accurate_answer = answers[0];
          let component_title:string = most_accurate_answer.metadata.usermeta['@COMPONENT_TITLE'];
          let most_accurate_AnswerBankItem = this.answerbankResponses.find(answerbankResponse => (answerbankResponse.title == component_title))
          const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(most_accurate_AnswerBankItem.component)
        }
        else{
          console.log("No answers from Answer Bank");
        }
      });      
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  let most_accurate_AnswerBankItem = this.answerbankResponses.find(answerbankResponse => (answerbankResponse.title == component_title))
```

`most_accurate_AnswerBankItem` can be `undefied` if nothing is found and in this case you don't have a `??` null check to provide an alternative value

the warning would go away if you wrap it in a if check before proceeding with any operation with a variable that is possibly undefined.

```
if(most_accurate_AnswerBankItem ){
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(most_accurate_AnswerBankItem.component)
}
```